# javascript code output Confusion on blank space even after passing a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, performance, reactjs

### Consider this code what will be the Output ?

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log(window.name);
    name = name || '<Your name here>';
    console.log('Hello ' + name);    
}
var a = "ton";
greet(a);
```

---

**I don't Understand why am I getting " " as a Output in First case here ? Why is window.name is " " , even when string "ton" is passed , shoudn't it be " ton " as first output ?**

Comment: `window.name` is the name of the `window`, usually blank by the way ... it's one of those "special" global properties that can really bugger you up :p - also note, that `window.anything` is not the same as a functions argument named `anything`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log(window.name);
    name = name || '<Your name here>';
    console.log('Hello ' + name);    
}
var a = "ton";
var name = "test"
greet(a);
```

If you declare global variable name like this you will get window.name

Answer (score 0):

Because the window object does not have a name property and you didn't set the name property of the window object.

You can set it either explicitly:

```
window.name = "ton";
```

or implicitly (in the global scope):

```
var name = "ton";
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.name` is not the same as the `name` function parameter. If you were to "execute" the code on paper, you'd start with your original code:

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log(window.name);
    name = name || '<Your name here>';
    console.log('Hello ' + name);    
}

var a = "ton";
greet(a);
```

The short-circuit evaluation of `||` in JavaScript makes the function more like this:

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log(window.name);
    if (name) {
        name = name;
    }
    else {
        name = '<Your name here>';
    }
    console.log('Hello ' + name);    
}

var a = "ton";
greet(a);
```

Optimizing a little bit, since setting `name` to itself if it's "truthy" (not null and not the empty string if you assume a string type) basically does nothing:

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log(window.name);
    if (!name) {
        name = '<Your name here>';
    }
    console.log('Hello ' + name);    
}

var a = "ton";
greet(a);
```

The next step would be:

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log(window.name);
    if (!name) {
        name = '<Your name here>';
    }
    console.log('Hello ' + name);    
}

greet("ton"); // this would be like passing "ton" a into greet.
```

Then:

```
console.log(window.name); // window.name is not the same as the name parameter.
if (!"ton") { // This doesn't evaluate to true ...
    // ... so we can forget about this part.
}
console.log('Hello ' + "ton");
```

Finally:

```
console.log(window.name);
console.log("Hello ton");
```

Since `window.name` is blank by default, you get the output you described.